# Show full tables using both LIKE & WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I need to select range of table names without views using only one query:

Example:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES LIKE '%table%' WHERE "Table_type"<>'VIEW'
```

MySQL does not allow to use these both operators in one query and it's using stupid column name like `Tables_in_(mydbname)` which contains DB name instead of using just simple column name like "Table_name". The problem is that I don't know the DB name, so I can't use the following query:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE "Table_type"<>'VIEW' AND "Tables_in_????" LIKE '%table%'
```

It would be great to use numbers instead of names like:

```
SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE COLUMN(1) LIKE '%table%' AND COLUMN(2) <>'VIEW'
```

but there is no such function.

I can't use INFORMATION_SCHEMA because the access to this table can be restricted by hosting provider (or I am wrong?) and my application is for wide distribution.

What would you advise me?

Answer (score 4):

Query the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html), in particular the [`TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) and [`COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) tables are interesting for you.

An example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
  JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    ON t.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG
   AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
   AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE [some field] LIKE '%some_value%'
   AND ...
```

Comment: @user1420069: You can edit your question then, to add that piece of information to it...

Comment: @LukasEder How can you read all that and make a perfect answer in under 2 minutes, it's impressive.

Comment: @radbyx: That was in 2012. I still dearly needed the rep.

Comment: I understand reps. must be important to you and it helps a lot to be fast and I respect it. I'm just blowned away how fast you guys can answer. Peace out :)